# Reinstall SSL cerificate on Exchange  server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, ssl-certificate

I bought a SSL certificate and installed it on an Exchange server, but unfortunately, I had to roll back the server to its previous snapshot.

How do i reinstall the certificate? (I didn't export it before the roll back.)

Comment: Had you already made the certificate request in the rolled-back state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to register for another certificate.  Contact the customer service company that you got the certificate from and explain what happened.  They'll make the current certificate invalid and issue you a new one.